# VBA Macro to interact with specific website

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, macros

I'm trying to get my macro to log me into a website.  So far I have it entering my username and password, But I'm at a loss on how to have it "click" the button.  The website is https://www.aum-inc.com/log-in and the log-in button isn't the one kind I know how to activate.  It has some sort of javascript. Below is my code, with HELP written by the two lines that I need to update for this specific case.

```
Sub AUM()
 'we define the essential variables
Dim ie As Object
Dim pwd, username
Dim button

'add the "Microsoft Internet Controls" reference in your VBA Project indirectly
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ("https://www.aum-inc.com/log-in")
    While ie.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Set username = .document.getElementById("cphContent_C001_txtUserName") 'id of the username control (HTML Control)
    Set pwd = .document.getElementById("cphContent_C001_txtPassword") 'id of the password control (HTML Control)
    'HELP Set button = .document.getElementById("ctl00$cphContent$C001$btnPropLogon") 'id of the button control (HTML Control)
    username.Value = "Account1234"
    pwd.Value = "Password1234"
    'HELP button.Click
    While ie.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
End With

'insert some sort of code in VBA to find account

Set ie = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Try, ie.document.getElementsbyName("btnsubmit")(0).click.

Answer (score 0):

That URL doesn't work for me, but this is essentially how you do it.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Login_2_Website()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Login"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.all.Email.Value = "sample@vbadud.com"
HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "*****"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Debug.Assert Err = 0
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

1. Microsoft Internet Controls
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library